# How to use platform.runlater() to disable link/hyperlink/navigation in one webview and open that link/hyperlink/navigation in another webview in java

Tags: java, jquery, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

[for reference i had attached my application screenshot if u see the page which is open up is also same and down one also same thats why i have to stop navigation of above webview so it can open in down one only ][1]

```
 public class HV extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
        {                   
            StackPane root = new StackPane();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(30); // create a HBox to hold 2 vboxes        

        // create a vbox with a textarea that grows vertically
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);  
        final WebView img = new WebView();
          final WebEngine webEngineImg = img.getEngine();     
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(img);

        // create a vbox that grows horizontally inside the hbox
        VBox vbox2 = new VBox();        
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
       final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

         final WebView browser1 = new WebView();
       final WebEngine webEngine1 = browser1.getEngine();
          webEngine1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
             primaryStage.setTitle(webEngine1.getLocation());
              String trgurl=webEngine1.getLocation();
              System.out.println(trgurl);


              if(trgurl.matches("(.*)img=(.*)")){

                  int n = trgurl.indexOf("img=");
                  //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
                  System.out.println(n+4);
                  int len = trgurl.length();
                  System.out.println("string length is: "+trgurl.length());
                  System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n+4,len));
                  String find = "file:"+trgurl.substring(n+4,len);
                  System.out.println(find);

                  webEngineImg.load(find);
                  //webEngine1.load(find);// this is loading image

                  if (trgurl.matches("(.*)target=wb2(.*)")){
                      //int n1= trgurl.indexOf("target=");
                      //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
                    //  System.out.println(n1+7);
                    //  System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n1+7,98));
                      boolean cancel();
                     webEngine.load("url");

                       }  
              }
             }
          }

        });

        webEngine1.load("url");
       // String url = "https://eclipse.org";
                // Load a page from remote url.
              //  webEngine.load(url);

        vbox2.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        vbox2.setSpacing(3);
         vbox2.getChildren().addAll( browser1,browser);

        HBox.setHgrow(vbox2, Priority.ALWAYS);


        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
//        StackPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(20));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox, vbox2);
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); // the stack pane is the root node


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);

    }
}
```

for debbuging - 
this is my code which have three webview in webview1 complete site open and in webviewimg only images from the action of webview1 open and in webview i want to load a edit url but for that i have to disable a navigation of that link in webview1 so that i can open that in webview so i had try platform.runlater to run that link after in other webview but im getting error that state cannot be change in to string this is a piece of code where im trying to add

```
webEngine1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
       .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
             primaryStage.setTitle(webEngine1.getLocation());
              String trgurl=webEngine1.getLocation();
              System.out.println(trgurl);
            if ((address.getQuery() + "").contains("target=true"))
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    grid_layout.getChildren().remove(webEngine1);
                    grid_layout.add(webEngine1, 0, 1);
                    webEngine1.load(oldState);
```

or how to insert jquery in java to prevent navigation code is here

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
 }, true);
```

Comment: i had acheve disabling the link with jquery embedded in javafx but it disable the click also i dont want to disable the click i just want that if i click on the link it should not not open in same webview it should open in another targetted webview is there is any class for that plz help required

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here is the code:

```
public class HV extends Application
{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{   

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    HBox hbox = new HBox(30); // create a HBox to hold 2 vboxes        

    // create a vbox with a textarea that grows vertically
    VBox vbox = new VBox(10);  
    final WebView img = new WebView();
      final WebEngine Img = img.getEngine();     
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(img);

    // create a vbox that grows horizontally inside the hbox
    VBox vbox2 = new VBox();        
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
   final WebEngine wb2 = browser.getEngine();

     final WebView browser1 = new WebView();
   final WebEngine wb1 = browser1.getEngine();
      wb1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
   .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    final WebEngine wb1 = browser1.getEngine();
                    if (wb1.getLocation().contains("img")) {
                        System.out.println("BrowserPane.ChangeListener cancelling " + wb1.getLocation());
                        wb1.getLoadWorker().cancel();
                        //  if (newState == Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {
                        primaryStage.setTitle(wb1.getLocation());
                        String trgurl = wb1.getLocation();
                        System.out.println(trgurl);
                           if(trgurl.matches("(.*)img=(.*)")){
              int n = trgurl.indexOf("img=");
              //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
              System.out.println(n+4);
              int len = trgurl.length();
              System.out.println("string length is: "+trgurl.length());
              System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n+4,len));
              String find = "file:"+trgurl.substring(n+4,len);
              System.out.println(find);

              Img.load(find);
                        //webEngine1.load(find);// this is loading image
                        if (trgurl.matches("(.*)target=wb2(.*)")){
                            int n1= trgurl.indexOf("target=wb2");
                            String str1 = Integer.toString(n1+10);
                            System.out.println(n1+10);
                            System.out.println(trgurl.substring(0,n1+10));
                            String find1= ""+trgurl.substring(0,n1+10);
                            System.out.println(find1);
                            // boolean cancel();
                            wb2.load(find1);
                        }
                        }
                        }  
                        });
                        } 
                        });






    wb1.load("url");
   // String url = "https://eclipse.org";
            // Load a page from remote url.
          //  webEngine.load(url);

    vbox2.setPadding(new Insets(3));
    vbox2.setSpacing(3);
     vbox2.getChildren().addAll( browser1,browser);

    HBox.setHgrow(vbox2, Priority.ALWAYS);


    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
//        StackPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(20));

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox, vbox2);
    root.getChildren().add(hbox);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); // the stack pane is the root node


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
 }  

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch(args);

}
}
```

By using platform.runlater() and after the listener cancel the loadworker by getloadworker.cancel()